# Is it possible to tell whether a function is in strict mode or not?

Tags: javascript

My question may sound weird but is there a way to understand whether a function is in strict mode or not by calling from another function?

```
function a(){
    "use strict";
    // Body
}

function b(){
// Body
}

function isStrict(fn){

    fn.call();
}

isStrict(a); // true
isStrict(b); // false
```

Comment: I know it's not my problem but I don't really understand how it could be useful to know that at compile time, except if you're manipulating callback within the function. In such case, instead of your callback, pass a test callback that would crash in case of strictmode so you can catch the error on top, and assume strict or not after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a function is affected by strict mode, `"use strict";` is prepended. So, the following check would be OK:

```
function isStrict(fn) {
    return typeof fn == 'function' &&
        /^function[^(]*\([^)]*\)\s*\{\s*(["'])use strict\1/.test(fn.toString())
        || (function(){ return this === undefined;})();
}
```

I used a RegExp to look for the `"use strict"` pattern at the beginning of the function's body.

To detect the global strict mode (which also affects a function), I'd [test one of the features](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/strict-mode/) to see whether strict mode is active.

Comment: That doesn't work universally, like for closures defined within a strict-mode module pattern.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the extra info. `(function() { 'use strict'; return function(){};})().toString()` gives `function (){\n"use strict";\n}` in Firefox, and `function (){}` in Chrome, so it works in some browsers.

Comment: Oh, interesting, I didn't know FF did that

Answer (score 1):

You could add an `isStrict` property to each function you make strict.

```
function a() {
    "use strict";
}
a.isStrict = true;

// ...
if ( a.isStrict ) { }
```

Comment: I think I found better way. Using `this`.

Comment: What do you mean? If I put `this.isStrict = true` inside the function, it would require calling the function to set the isStrict property.

Comment: I agree with Esailija on your answer. You shouldn't have to call the function, as that may cause unwanted side effects.

Comment: Thanks. Parsing seems to be the solution.